# React - How to check/uncheck checkboxes in a loop whose values come from redux store

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, redux

I am trying to build a Notification settings via React and Redux where my against each email address I have few checkboxes say something in the below format.

```
 import React from 'react'

export class NotificationSettings extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getEmailUserRows = this.getEmailUserRows.bind(this)
}


getEmailUserRows() {
    let _this = this
    let emailRows = this.props.emailRows
    let emailTemplate = emailRows.map((row) => {
        return (
            <tr key={row.email}>
                <td height="70">
                    <span class="txt-limit">
                        <small>{row.email}</small>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                            id={row.email+"sttng1"}
                            name={row.email+"sttng1"}
                            type="checkbox"/>
                        <label for="sttng1"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                            id={row.email+"sttng2"}
                            name={row.email+"sttng2"}
                            type="checkbox"/>
                        <label for="sttng2"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                             id={row.email+"sttng3"}
                            name={row.email+"sttng3"}
                            type="checkbox"/>
                        <label for="sttng3"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                             id={row.email+"sttng4"}
                            name={row.email+"sttng4"}
                            type="checkbox"/>
                        <label for="sttng4"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                            id={row.email+"sttng5"}
                            name={row.email+"sttng5"}
                            type="checkbox"
                            />
                        <label for="sttng5"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="icon-delete"></span>
                </td>

            </tr>
        )
    })

    return emailTemplate

}
render() {
    return (

        <div class="accordian-container open">
            <div class="webhook-dtl">
                <h4>Notification Settings</h4>
                <table
                    width="100%"
                    border="0"
                    cellSpacing="0"
                    cellPadding="0"
                    class="transaction-detail">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="tbl-hdng">
                            <td width="24%" height="52" align="left">Email ID</td>
                            <td width="19%" class="no-spc">Transactional<br/>Emails</td>
                            <td width="13%" class="no-spc">Settlement<br/>Emails</td>
                            <td width="12%" class="no-spc">CRM<br/>Emails</td>
                            <td width="12%" class="no-spc">Onboarding<br/>Emails</td>
                            <td width="10%" class="no-spc">Other<br/>Emails</td>
                            <td width="10%" class="no-spc">Action</td>
                        </tr>
                        {this.getEmailUserRows()}

                    </tbody>
                </table><br/>
                <br/>
                <button class="cmn-btn right">ADD&nbsp;MORE</button>

            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
}

export default NotificationSettings
```

My JSON that is stored in the redux store:

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "rows": 0,
  "message": "Merchant Details returned successfully",
  "result": [
    {
      "email": "dashboard2@yopmail.com",
      "emailCategoryList": {
        "crmEmails": true,
        "settlementEmails": true,
        "transactionalEmails": true,
        "onboardingEmails": true,
        "otherEmails": true
      },
      "isMerchantBusinessEmail": true
    },
    {
      "email": "vinikaty@gmail.com",
      "emailCategoryList": {
        "crmEmails": true,
        "settlementEmails": false,
        "transactionalEmails": false,
        "onboardingEmails": true,
        "otherEmails": true
      },
      "isMerchantBusinessEmail": false
    }
  ],
  "errorCode": null,
  "guid": null
}
```

Pleae help me check/uncheck checkboxes in React not able to figure out what would be the best approach.

**EDIT:**

Made changes as suggested:

```
`import React from 'react';


let NotificationSettingRow = (props) => {
  let { emailRowData } = props

  const toggleCheckbox = () => {
   console.log("Yay")
  }


  return (
     <tr key={emailRowData.email}>
                <td height="70">
                    <span class="txt-limit">
                        <small>{emailRowData.email}</small>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                            id={emailRowData.email+"sttng1"}
                            name={emailRowData.email+"sttng1"}
                            {...(emailRowData.emailCategoryList.transactionalEmails ? {checked: true} : {}) }
                            onChange={toggleCheckbox}
                            type="checkbox"/>
                        <label for="sttng1"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                            id={emailRowData.email+"sttng2"}
                            name={emailRowData.email+"sttng2"}
                            type="checkbox"/>
                        <label for="sttng2"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                             id={emailRowData.email+"sttng3"}
                            name={emailRowData.email+"sttng3"}
                            type="checkbox"/>
                        <label for="sttng3"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                             id={emailRowData.email+"sttng4"}
                            name={emailRowData.email+"sttng4"}
                            type="checkbox"/>
                        <label for="sttng4"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="pure-checkbox tog-check">
                        <input
                            id={emailRowData.email+"sttng5"}
                            name={emailRowData.email+"sttng5"}
                            type="checkbox"
                            />
                        <label for="sttng5"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-spc" height="70">
                    <span class="icon-delete"></span>
                </td>

            </tr>
  )
}


export default NotificationSettingRow`
```

However i am unable to check/uncheck checkboxes. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at he last line in input, it basically evaluates if email in current row is in particular category, and if yes it renders checked=true, otherwise renders nothing

```
<input
   id={row.email+"sttng1"}
   name={row.email+"sttng1"}
   type="checkbox"
   {...(row.emailCategoryList.crmEmails ? {checked: true} : {}) }
/>
```

While you are at it you could define your component that would be used like:

```
<MyMailCheck row={row} idPrefix="sttng1" rowKey="crmEmails"/>
```

to avoid typing pretty much the same code for each email category.

Now how to handle checking and unchecking by the user. You need action that will be fired by the onClick for each checkbox. Something along these lines:

```
const emailCategoryClick = (email, category) => ({
  type: 'EMAIL_CATEGORY_CLICK',
  email,
  category
})
```

And you need suitable reducer to recognize this action, and update state accordingly.

Lastly, you need to wire your checkboxes to dispatch correct emailCategoryClick actions. To do so, you should connect your component to get access to dispatch method from store. Something like:

```
export default connect(
 (state) => ({}),
 (dispatch) => ({catClick: (email, cat) => () => {dispatch(emailCategoryClick(email, cat))} })
)(NotificationSettings)
```

and in your checkbox you would add onClick handler as in:

```
<input
   id={row.email+"sttng1"}
   name={row.email+"sttng1"}
   type="checkbox"
   {...(row.emailCategoryList.crmEmails ? {checked: true} : {}) }
   onCLick={catClick(row.email, "crmEmails")}
/>
```

Comment: I understand this makes sense how do i handle the checking and unchecking of these checkboxes?

Comment: ok, I have added explanation on how to handle user clicks. I have not ncluded reducer code sice I believe that should be straight forward. If you are not sure about expressions like (email, cat) => () => {dispatch(emailCategoryClick(email, cat))} then try reading about currying https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/

Comment: Thanks a ton. however my click on the checkbox isn't triggering no idea why

Comment: first step would be to test if action and reducer you have written are working correctly. It is easiest to do so by using redux deveopment tools for chrome which lets you see all actions that get dispatched and the state fom the store. So you could manually invoke dispatch emailCategoryClick and see if the state has changed accordingly. Once that works ok, you can try clicking on checkboxes and see if appropriate action is dispatched.